# How do I exclude columns which start with a specific string in MDX?

Tags: sql, mdx, business-intelligence, cube

I'm trying to write an MDX query with the equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.CID, m.Orders
FROM dbo.Measures as m
WHERE SUBSTRING(m.CID, 1, 4) <> 'PID_'
```

Essentially, exclude all rows where CID begins with `'PID_'`

This is what I have in MDX so far:

```
SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[ID] AS ID,
    [Measures].[Orders] AS NumberOfOrders,
}
ON COLUMNS, 
{
    [Channel].[Channel Account ID].[Channel Account ID].Members
    * [Channel].[Channel].[Channel].Members // exclude accounts starting with 'PID_'
}
```

I've tried `EXCEPT` and `-` and `WHERE` clauses, but none seem to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 10 seconds google search reveals lots of options... http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1293/how-to-use-a-like-operator-in-mdx or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/a354c898-2816-4cb5-b318-09b8befb2b17/ to name 2

Comment: @xQbert I didn't find those pages with my searches, I promise you, I spent about 4 hours trying to get this working yesterday and today before I asked it :)  I'll give both of those a try.

Comment: I'm glad you got what you needed out of the search results.  I'm not a big fan of "doing the work" but the research. Well that's fun.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks.  Sometimes the hardest part in starting something new is knowing how to phrase the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with the links xQbert provided.

This was the answer:

```
ON COLUMNS, 
{
    FILTER([Channel].[Channel Account ID].[Channel Account ID].Members, 
        LEFT([Channel].[Channel Account].Properties("Channel Account ID"), 4) 
            <> "PID_")
    * [Channel].[Channel].[Channel].Members
}
```